# Using Mockito doAnswer in Kotlin

Tags: testing, mockito, kotlin

what would be the Kotlin equivalent to this Java code?

```
doAnswer(new Answer() {
    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        Design design = new Design();
        GetDesign.Listener callback = (GetDesign.Listener) invocation.getArguments()[0];
        callback.onSuccess(design);
        return null;
    }
}).when(someRepository).getDesign(any(GetDesign.Listener.class));
```

[UPDATE] After trying several options, I finally made it work using [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin). I think that's the most comfortable way of implementing `doAnswer`. Syntax remains almost the same:

```
doAnswer {
    callback = it.arguments[0] as GetDesign.Listener
    callback.onSuccess(Design())
    null
}.whenever(someRepository).execute(any(GetDesign.Listener::class.java))
```

Complete code and build.gradle configuration can be found [here](https://github.com/voghDev/HelloKotlin/blob/master/app/src/test/java/es/voghdev/hellokotlin/SomeAsyncPresenterTest.kt)

Comment: Note: I suggest looking into these Kotlin Mockito bindings: https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin.  They give you a bunch of cool stuff (e.g. `whenever` instead of `\`when\``).

Comment: I Had a look at it, but does it work with Kotlin 1.1.1?

Comment: I guess you need to do a SAM conversion. See here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions

Comment: Works on my machine :)

Comment: Made it work too using mockito-kotlin. trying to make it work 'the original way', will update answer once I reach some conclusion

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
doAnswer {
    val design = Design()

    val callback = it.arguments[0] as GetDesign.Listener
    callback.onSuccess(design)

    null // or you can type return@doAnswer null

}.`when`(someRepository).getDesign(any(GetDesign.Listener::class.java))
```

Comment: @voghDev if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: It is indeed the right answer. I would just replace `when` with whenever, as mockito-kotlin adds this function that looks a bit cleaner. I'll also update question text. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am a fan of Full Mocking object, I don't want loading any configuration or any other spring boot dependency injection kicking in.

If I have to Mock a JavaMailSender function I will do it like this. I will use `theAnswer` to return the value.

#### Kotlin (Just Test JavaMailSender)

```
@Test
fun javaMailSenderTest(){
val jms = mock(JavaMailSender::class.java)
val mimeMessage = mock(MimeMessage::class.java)
mimeMessage.setFrom("no-reply@example.com")
mimeMessage.setText("Just a body text")

Mockito.`when`(jms.send(mimeMessage)).thenAnswer {
  // val callback = it.arguments[0]  <- Use these expression to get params values
  // Since JavaMailSender::send() function retrun void therefore, we should return Unit
  Unit
}

assertEquals(jms.send(mimeMessage), Unit)
```

}

#### Kotlin (Using Custom Class for JavaMailSender)

chances are that you might be using your own Custom class for sending mail, so here I have done it.

```
@Test
fun updateMembers&SendEmailTest() {

val mockEmailService= mock(MyEmailServiceImplementor::class.java)

// sendInfoMail(true|false) is my custom implemention of JavaMailSender
Mockito.`when`(mockEmailService.sendInfoMail(true)).thenAnswer { invocation ->
  Unit
}

assertEquals(mockEmailService.sendInfoMail(true), Unit)
```

}

Hope this helps somebody. If you need a Java version let me know in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you could also do something like this (assuming the type is `Repository`):

```
    mock<Repository>() {
        on { getDesign(any() as GetDesign.Listener) } doAnswer {
            val callback = it.arguments[0] as GetDesign.Listener
            callback.onSuccess(Design())
            null
        }
    }
```