# doNothing() does not work when i want to mock data and test UI Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito, android-espresso, ui-testing

I am going to **test** `fragment` with **Espresso** then i want to **mock** `viewmodels` and members.

In my `viewModel` i have a `void` `function` like this :

```
fun getLoginConfig() {
    viewModelScope.launchApiWith(_loginConfigLiveData) {
       repository.getLoginConfig()
    }
}
```

In test `fragment` when we call `getLoginConfig()` from `viewModel` i want to **mock** it with `doNothing()` but i **faced** with this `error` :

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here


E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
 3. you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction is completed
```

At this line on `testFragmentClass` :

```
   @Before
    fun setUp() {
        //logOut


        mockVm = mock(SplashVM::class.java)

        loadKoinModules(module {
            single {
                mockVm
            }
        })
}




   doNothing().`when`(mockVm.getLoginConfig()).let {
       mockVm.loginConfigLiveData.postValue(Resource.Success(
           LoginConfigResponse(
               listOf("1"),1,1,"1",true)
       ))
   }
```

Comment: In your test, does `getLoginConfig` return a mock or a real value? Is `mockVm` a mock, or is it a spy?

Comment: `mockVm` is a mock and `getLoginConfig()` is a void func in `viewModel` that we call an API from it and fill the `liveData` with that `response` , then i want to fill the `livedata` with my fake `response`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- `doNothing` just does nothing, which is unnecessary for void methods on a mock. It's the default behavior. You only want `doNothing` for spies or already-stubbed mocks.
- If you want something specific to happen in response to a call on a mock, [`doAnswer` is the way to go](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44066993/1426891).
- In `doVerb` syntax, Mockito expects that there is only a variable there; the expression should not call a method on a mock, or else Mockito thinks you've lost interest and throws UnfinishedStubbingException.

Therefore your fix looks like:

```kotlin
doAnswer {
  mockVm.loginConfigLiveData.postValue(Resource.Success(
    LoginConfigResponse(
      listOf("1"),1,1,"1",true)
  ))
}.`when`(mockVm).getLoginConfig()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but `loginConfigLiveData` still fill with real `response` (404 and failed) and did not fill with fake `response`   `mockVm.loginConfigLiveData.postValue(Resource.Success(
    LoginConfigResponse(
      listOf("1"),1,1,"1",true)
  ))`

Comment: @milad Can you confirm that SplashVM and `getLoginConfig()` are both `open`? Honestly it's surprising that `loginConfigLiveData` is populated at all, since `mock` doesn't run constructors. If the class and method are `final` (Java) or non-`open` (Kotlin), that would explain the behavior you see.

Comment: Yes before error was about SplashVM `final`  `class` that i solved it with https://kotlinlang.org/docs/all-open-plugin.html#gradle , maybe `mock` process has a problem. @Jeff Bowman

Comment: @miladsalimi I cannot help further; this is not a problem I can reproduce or observe myself, so all I can do is guess in the dark. I believe you'll need to create a [mcve] for more help.